# Builders - creates a new instance each time?

Tags: android, builder

I'm using a couple of Builders to make a bunch of objects. What I'm currently doing is this:

```
List<ProductofBuilder> list;
Builder b = new Builder();

for(some iterable i in I) {
    b.setSomeParam(i);
    list.add(b.build());
}
```

Is this okay to do? In other words, does a builder create a new instance of `ProductOfBuilder` each `build()`?

Comment: I don't see any issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't totally clear in the question that I was `build`ing each time. Sorry about that.

Running this code:

```
    ArrayList<ScanSettings> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ScanSettings.Builder b = new ScanSettings.Builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        b.setReportDelay(i * 100);
        list.add(b.build());
    }
```

gives the following result in the debugger.

[image]

so they all have unique memory addresses, and each one has the unique reportDelay too.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this okay to do? In other words, does a builder create a new
>   instance of ProductOfBuilder each

No it is not. Accordingly to the code you posted you are changing always the same reference. In  the end your list will contains n builder, with the content of the last call to   `setSomeParam`.

It is different if you have a `Collection` of objects the builder is supposed to build, and you are calling at every iteration `build()`.

```
List<TypeToBuild> list;
TypeToBuild.Bilder builder;
for (Type t : parmas) {
   builder.setParamns(t);
   list.add(builder.build());
 }
```

Comment: So I actually tested the code, and this works fine. See my answer

Comment: it is my fault. I was looking at the code and there was no call to build(). But you were adding the builder itself to the list

Comment: oh shoot. I thought I had included that in the question :P